# SVG text losing color and position on tooltip <div>?

Tags: html, css, svg, tooltip

I'm trying to put a tooltip on a SVG text, but when the SVG is inserted on the tooltip DIV, it loses the positioning and color styling.

```html
<div class="tooltip">
<text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-102,54)"
style="font-size: 100px; fill: rgb(107, 110, 207); font-family: Impact;">SVG WORD</text>
<span class="tooltiptext">TOOLTIP</span>
</div>
```

Can anybody lend me a hand so the coloring and positiong don't go away?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do but you can't mix html and SVG tags like that. All SVG tags such as <text> must have an <svg> ancestor.

Comment: Oh, I see. But how can I add a tooltip in a svg text with its own style (like I showed on the 1st post)?